# External Static ip for docker container

Tags: docker

I have a machine which has docker installed on it. Let's say it has an ip 10.100.50.157 which is reachable from another PC in the same network. Now i want to create a docker container which has a static ip in another subnet so the ip is 10.100.32.246 and subnet 10.100.32.0/24 and gateway is 10.100.32.1 so i tried doing what is explained in this article https://blog.jessfraz.com/post/ips-for-all-the-things/ like this:

```
docker network create --subnet 10.100.32.0/24 --gateway 10.100.32.1 iptastic
docker run --rm -it --net ipstatic --ip 10.100.32.246 nginx
```

And then i can on the docker host do a curl 10.100.32.246 and get a response but from another machine on the network i cannot reach this.

The network created in linux looks like this :

```
br-68fef88a0b8a: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:8c:44:8d:71 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.100.32.1/24 brd 10.100.32.255 scope global br-68fef88a0b8a
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:8cff:fe44:8d71/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

i find it weird that this network has the ip of the gateway, i mean the ip addr should not be the gateway since there is a gateway on the network with that ip. I am pretty sure that i have misunderstood the concept with this network and what i want to achieve.

So i guess i need some help figuring out how i can achieve that i can curl to 10.100.32.246 and the same time still reach the docker host on it's ip 10.100.50.157 from the local network.

Comment: Have you considered just using port mapping instead (`docker run -p host_port:container_port ...`)? Does your container really need an ip on the physical network, or do you simply need to expose a *service* on the physical network?

Comment: Yes i did consider a port forwarding but my problem is that the machine needs its own hostname which in turn needs an ip which is different from the host

Comment: So add multiple ips to your host (`ip address add 1.2.3.4/32 dev eth0`). And use those ips when forwarding ports (`-p 1.2.3.4:80:80`).